# Connection breaks for FastAPI app behind AWS Load Balancer while streaming payload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, networking, fastapi

I have a fastapi app with an endpoint like this:

```
@app.post("/api/.../")
async def overall_flow(request: Request):
    data: dict = await request.json()
    ...
```

This is hosted on aws fargate and made accessible through an ALB.
Sometimes it happens that (only on some bigger payloads it seems - not sure though) the connection seems to break while still retrieving the request. We get the following error in the logs:

```
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) data: dict = await request.json()   backend-api
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 243, in json backend-api
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) body = await self.body()    backend-api
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 236, in body backend-api
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) async for chunk in self.stream():   backend-api
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 230, in stream   backend-api
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) raise ClientDisconnect()    backend-api
August 25, 2023 at 16:02 (UTC+2:00) starlette.requests.ClientDisconnect
```

What could be the cause of this? (General ideas are also highly appreciated)

Comment: Exceeding default ALB idle timeout of 60 seconds?

Comment: No, I already set the limit up...

Comment: Any news regarding this issues, I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Sry to be honest I don't remember how we solved this, it might have been caused by unstable internet on the client side, I'm not sure though